# Why is the Absolute Value of $3-π$ equal to $π - 3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers

Why if the absolute value is the distance from $0$ on the number line, is $\lvert 3-\pi \rvert = \pi - 3$
and $\left\lvert\sqrt{2}-1\right\rvert= \sqrt{2}-1$

Comment: Because $\pi > 3$ and $\sqrt{2}>1$.

Comment: Because ${\pi>3}$

Comment: What is that weird symbol?

Comment: @DavidMitra which one?

Comment: The real problem here is a misunderstanding of how the absolute value is defined I think.

Comment: @VladimirVargas The one that looks like a mirror image of $\pi$.

Comment: Check [the absolute value function definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value).

Comment: @DavidMitra It's http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03C0/index.htm

Comment: $|3-\pi|=\pi-3$ because $3<\pi$.

Answer (score 5):

First recall the *definition* of the absolute value:
$$
|x|=\begin{cases}
x, & x\geq 0, \\
-x, & x<0.
\end{cases}
$$
Now think about what this means for your two examples.

**Example 1:** We consider $|3-\pi|$. Well, we know that $\pi>3$. Thus, by using the definition of the absolute value, we can see that
$$
|3-\pi|=-(3-\pi)=\pi-3.
$$

**Example 2:** We consider $|\sqrt{2}-1|$. Well, we know that $\sqrt{2}>1$. Thus, again, by using the definition of the absolute value, we can see that
$$
|\sqrt{2}-1|=\sqrt{2}-1.
$$

It certainly helps to think about absolute values in terms of the number line, but the above is how to handle it algebraically. Does it make sense now?

---

Here is the picture of the number line:

[image]

Note that the *absolute* value is the *distance* from $0$, and this explains both my algebraic answer and the number line above.

Answer (score 4):

$|x| = \begin{cases} x &\textrm{if} ~~ x \geq 0 \\ -x &\textrm{if} ~~ x <0\end{cases}$

So applying this to your example gives $|3 - \pi| = -(3 - \pi) = \pi - 3$ because $3 - \pi < 0$.

Comment: I can see that you utilized the distributive property and factored out the negative sign. However, you are not giving a clear idea why you are allowed to do that. Is it because there is a negative sign between the two terms?

Comment: @Cetshwayo Since $(3-\pi)+(\pi-3)=0$, we get that $-(3-\pi)=\pi-3$. The distributive property is not used, only commutativity and associativity of addition. Recall that $a-b$ is short for $a+(-b)$ and $-b$ denotes the opposite of $b$, that is, the number that summed to $b$ gives $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$|3-\pi|$ is always going to be whichever of $3-\pi$ or $\pi-3$ which is *positive*.

Since $\pi > 3$, the latter is going to be positive.

Comment: Okay so I am basically doing the math within the absolute value equation.If the calculation within the bars is negative, I utilized -a if a<0 and if it is a positive value I utilize the same value?

Comment: @Cetshwayo  That is correct.  Since $\pi - 3 > 0$, $|\pi - 3| = \pi - 3$.  Since $3 - \pi < 0$, $|3 - \pi| = -(3 - \pi) = -3 + \pi = \pi - 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, $|a|$ is $a$ if $a>0$ and $-a$ if $a<0$.

Hence :
$$\sqrt{2}<2 \iff \sqrt{2}-2<0$$
$$\iff |\sqrt{2}-2|=-(\sqrt{2}-2)=\sqrt{2}-1$$

Same goes for $3-\pi$ :
$$3<\pi \iff 3-\pi<0$$
$$\iff |3-\pi|=-(3-\pi)=\pi-3$$

Comment: So am I setting |\sqrt 2 - 1| > and < 0 then determining whether it fits into the one of the absolute value definitions, then utilizing the definition to determine its value?

Answer (score 0):

Remember how the subtraction is defined on the number line:

[image: subtraction on number line]

*File [Number line with addition of -2 and 3.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Number_line_with_addition_of_-2_and_3.svg) from Wikimedia Commons*

When you have $x-y$ with $x > y$ you will get an result on the right hand side of the origin. Thus its absolute value (= distance from zero) is the number itself. The above picture show that $|3-2|=3-2$. In the same way you can explain $|\sqrt{2}-1|=\sqrt{2}-1$.

The case $|3-\pi|$ can also be easily explained on the number line.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: $|x|=-x$ if $x<0.$..

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you use the example to explain?

Comment: Here is an example:  $|-5| = 5 = -1 \cdot -5$.